# Debug Flutter app on Vscode but built with Xcode on a physical Iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I bought a Macbook recently and I am struggling to set up my environment. Before, I used my android phone to test apps, and it was just plug, build and debug, with hot reload/restart, but now with a Macbook and an Iphone, I just can't seem to make it work. I am building the app through Xcode, but is there some way to link my app to VSCode to make use of the debug and hot reload/restart?

Dunno what I should put here, like configuration files or something, so let me know if there is anything that is needed to help me. Thanks.

Comment: Navigate through Finder to your project. Then go to the IOS folder and drag and drop the Runner.xcworkspace on Xcode. You have to create a simulator, build the project for the simulator. For real device you have to connect the device, build the project from Xcode on your device, and then run debug from your VS. Check out this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCwXGB6Olt4 ), and always check the officials docs.

Comment: I went through the same thing a year ago -- had a working Android app build on Windows / VSCode / Android simulator.  Bought a MAC and an iPhone, and found myself overwhelmed by the process.  Suggest you confirm your tools are all up-to-date -- latest flutter, dart, all the VSCode add-ins.  Then create a new, simple project. You should be able to select an iOS device from VSCode and run it in the debugger the same way you can with Android.

Comment: Clarification -- my suggestion doesn't address running on a physical device, just a simulator.